# BIOS flash possible?

Tags: bios

Not sure if it's the right forum to post this but have been modifying the BIOS of my Asus N551VW (which is a skylake laptop (I7-6700HQ) with an AMI Aptio BIOS) and I'm ready to flash it.

Problem is, I've heard that some little evil thing called "Intel BootGuard" exists inside the skylake laptops that prevents the pc from booting if a non-stock BIOS is detected...

I would love to enable the option to disable my Intel HD530 for hackintosh purposes but seems like it's impossible again despite the modding tools being super easy to use (like afuwin, amibcp).

Do these Asus laptops (like the GL551VW, GL552VW, N551VW...) have intel bootguard in them? If so, can it be bypassed somehow?

Thanks!